# Kendo ui grid - filter with ajax post

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I´m trying to filter my datasource but using a ajax post, and the reason is, i have a condition on main **main** GET on my server side which does this:

```
WHERE idPai IS NULL OR idPai = 0
```

Now what i want is to filter the datsource but **without** that condition on my server side, so first what i have done was:

```
       var value = $("#inputPastaFiltro").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "basedados.php",
        data: {dataFilter:value},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) 
        {
           $('#gridBaseDados').data('kendoGrid').dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: result.data[0] }).query({
            filter:{
              logic:"or",
              filters:[
                {field:"nome", operator:"contains",value:result.data[0].nome}]  
             }
          });
        },
```

On the server side, i have create a:

```
else if($_POST['dataFilter'])
```

with the same GET i have but without the condition i have wrote above, this way(i think) it searches for everything, but the rest of the logic is not correct has you already realized. If i do just like this:

```
var value = $("#inputPastaFiltro").val();
dataSource.query({
                filter:{
                  logic:"or",
                  filters:[
                    {field:"nome", operator:"contains",value:value}]  
                 }
              });
```

it works very well, and it also does that dynamic search of refreshing the grid as soon as you insert the words in the input(which is great!)...but it is based on my MAIN GET which has that condition.

Can anyone give me some help?, sorry for the bad english.

Regards.

Comment: Did you forget this ?

Comment: Nothing, but it passed some days since you've posted, but np.

Comment: thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create a dataSource with the array `result.data[0]`, the *filter* will be performed over that data. So I think you want to execute the query again, when the filter it performed, right? The way you're calling the ajax request isn't nice when applied with kendo. You should do like that :

```
$('#gridBaseDados').kendoGrid({
    ...
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: function(options) {
                $.ajax({
                    ...
                    success: function(result) {
                        options.success(result.data[0]);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Using a function in `dataSource.transport.read` is the best way. So you have the `options` argument, which has the `success` callback of the dataSource. This will overwrite the default dataSource's request and then the entire behiviour is preserved. Your filters should work as expected. They will call that `read` function each time it is changed.

Give it a try and tell us the results. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, and please help me out understanding something, where does the GET distinction appears? because at this very moment, i have the normal GET(which has the condition) and i have a elseIf for a POST where the select to the database doesn´t have any conditions(which i need)...so in the success callback, how is it filtering?...I´m asking this, because (i really don´t know) but doesn´t the read/options rely on my server side select?, so if that select is already filtered...man!, i´m lost. sorry

Comment: @Japa that's right, it doesn't changes the protocol type, but you can do it before the request. You can check if dataSource has filters, or, you can fix that in your PHP to use always post or get, which is imo the best way.